# Excel - Test if two consecutive digits in the range's address are the same

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I want to offset a range if the numerical part of a range's address can be divided by 11.
(A11, A22, A33, and so forth).

Take a range in a given sheet, for example Range("A2").
Could I do ...

```
        Dim isRng as Range
        Dim rngAddress as String
        Dim tstAddress as Integer, nsnAddress as Integer
 
        isRng = Range("A2")
        isRng.Select 
        rngAddress = isRng.Address
```

Currently, rngAddress = $A$2 (I think). So then, could I ...

```
        tstAddress = Right(rngAddress, 2)
        nsnAddress = Right(tstAddress, 1)

        If tstAddress / nsnAddress = 11 Then
             'whatever code
             Set isRng = ActiveCell.Offset(4,0).Select
        Else
        End If
```

I want it to skip down 4 rows after hitting any range like A11 or A22.
Would this work? Is there a better way of doing this? I really appreciate the help.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
Sub sully_was_here()
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = [a22]
    With r
        .Select
        If .Row Mod 11 = 0 Then
            'whatever code here
            .Offset(4).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked with Selection.Row  Thank you! I chose this since the code was shorter.

Comment: I don't want it to skip the first 11th row. What's the best approach to that?

Comment: You can set `r` to anything you want. For example `Set r = [a11]`

Comment: I see. Would the syntax of this make sense "If r = [a11] Then" ? I already have a loop running through a range and I want it to skip certain cells, including cells like A11.

Comment: You should use this syntax: `If r.Row Mod 11 = 0 Then`

Comment: Right, but then it skips A11. Could I do If r.Row Mod 11 = 0 And ActiveCell.Row = 11 Or ActiveCell.Row (n) Then 'skip the code Else r.Row Mod 11 = 0  'do the code ??

Comment: Yes. If this logic is more complex you can incrementally add an `And` clause...

Answer (score 1):

### Divisible: Using `Mod`

```
If cCell.Row Mod 11 = 0 Then
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Divisible()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A2:A33")
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    
    For Each cCell In rg.Cells
        r = r + 1
        If cCell.Row Mod 11 = 0 Then
            Debug.Print r, cCell.Offset(4).Address, "***"
        Else
            Debug.Print r, cCell.Address
        End If
    Next cCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This also worked! I appreciate the timely response